# I cant put block in the correct place with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, block

can someone help me please, I need to do like this

[an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTcqn.jpg)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-6" >A</div>
<div class="col-md-12">B</div>
<div class="col-md-6">C</div>
</div>
```

My starting code above. please help me

Comment: unfortunately, you won't be able to do that because it would take rearranging of the dom. One way you could do it is duplicate C and have it hide or show based on the media query.

Comment: Use display: flex with order: 1, 2,3 with media queries. That will also work.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using **push** and/ or **pull**. Check out this link https://scotch.io/tutorials/reorder-css-columns-using-bootstrap.

The order of column A needs to remain constant, while B and C need to be switched so that on larger screens, C is ahead of B.

Answer (score 0):

You can use display: flex; and reorder items

Answer (score 0):

Since you have col-12 to swap with col-6 so push and pull won't really work, I could only think of using hidden/show. see example below:

```css
.container div {
  background: aqua;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container row">
  <div class="col-md-6">A</div>
  <div class="col-md-12 hidden-md hidden-lg">B</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">C</div>
  <div class="col-md-12 hidden-xs hidden-sm">B</div>
</div>
```